# .htacces rewrite url is not working?

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone help me with this. htaccess 
he does the right mp4 
if I type in the url without. mp4 then who does not

```
MVG kenny   
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.mp4 [NC,L]
MVG kenny
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your rule with this one line:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.